# React JS - Error - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs

I am using Axios function , to return an API call to response data as below.

```
componentDidMount(){
 axios.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").then(response => {
      response.data 
      this.setState({stateData:response.data});
   });
}
```

But I am getting the below error while compiling.
`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`.
When I remove the line `respose.data`, it is working. But not returning the result.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to :

```
axios.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").then(response=>{
    this.setState({stateData:response.data});
    return response.data ;
});
```

The code in `{}` of `then(response => {/* function body */})` is the body of a function, and `then` returns the result of that function.